# How to share individual images in facebook

Tags: facebook, caching, share, feed

I would like to enable users to share a certain feed with dynamically generated pictures. This means that the picture url is always a new one.

However, it seems that the picture Facebook is using is not that from the URL but always (an old) one from the cache.

The URL is something like http://www.domain.com/facebook/unique-picture.png

How is it possible to turn off the caching?

```
  function shareMessage(link) {
    alert(link);

    FB.ui(
            {
                method: 'feed',
                name: link,
                link: 'link',
                picture: link,
                caption: link,
                description: "description",
                message: ''
            });
   }
```

Comment: Is the picture URL different each time? We only download each image URL once so you'll need to make them unique.

Comment: Hi, the picture urls are already unique in following way: http://www.domain.com/facebook/UUID.png
Nevertheless, it does not work.

Comment: Is there somewhere I can actually try it out and see the wrong image being displayed?